# Android: identifier not declared

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7

Here's my code:

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas); 
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Randomize;
  Paintbox1.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clWhite;
  Paintbox1.Canvas.Rectangle(0,500,500,0);
  Paintbox1.Canvas.MoveTo(1,0);
  Paintbox1.Canvas.LineTo(1,500);
  Paintbox1.Canvas.Pixels[xx,yy]:=clBlack;
  ...
end;
```

When I try to compile this code, I get:

> identifier not declared
>   'Brush','Color','Rectangle','MoveTo','LineTo','TextOut','Pixels'.

Answer (score 3):

Error identifier not declared means that your PaintBox1 object does not contain properties and methods 'Brush', 'Color', 'Rectangle'...

In this case it happened because Delphi uses new FireMonkey (FMX) framework for Android development and not VCL. Classes and controls in those two frameworks have completely different roots and while they do share some similarities, their functionality, properties and methods are quite different. Bottom line is that you cannot use same code you have used for Windows development with VCL.

More information about FMX TCanvas class you can find at:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7//en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas_Properties
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7//en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas_Methods

As you can see, FMX TCanvas does no longer have 'Brush' property but 'Fill' and 'Stroke' brushes.

```
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.White;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.FillRect(RectF(0, 0, 500, 500), 0, 0, AllCorners, 1);

  PaintBox1.Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Blue;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Stroke.Thickness := 1;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Stroke.Join := TStrokeJoin.Miter;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.DrawLine(TPointF.Create(1, 0), TPointF.Create(1, 500), 1);
```